# Having trouble with Grunt auto-reload

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm trying to set up live-reload in my grunt file, but I cannot get it to work. I am working from my `htdocs/` directory in my `MAMP` application. From what I researched, you have to use your port in the options for the grunt watch, but even after trying this I cannot get my browser to live reload. Also in my research on this topic, I found that I may need to have to download the Chrome Extension 'LiveReload', so I went ahead and did that but still no auto reload. Im working from `localhost:8888/`+the directory of the site I'm making edits to, so for my current project `localhost:8888/haulzi`. My watch task is below, is anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

```
  watch: {
less: {
  files: ['less/*.less'],
  tasks: ['less:production'],
  options:{
      livereload: 8888;
  }
},
uglify: {
  files: ['js/main.js'],
  tasks: ['uglify:production']
}
}
```

note: I have also tried `livereload: true`

Comment: You reference `less` files in your html? Also I think your livereload port should be different from your web server.

Comment: Setting `livereload: true` should start the watcher on the default port.

Comment: set livereload to true (default port), start your grunt task, open your browser and click the chrome extension. after that you should see in the dev-tools, that there is a connection. if so, your watcher needs some configuration